# Simplifying a expression containing an even function

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I want to simplify a expression with a even function `Df[x] == Df[-x]`

```
  FullSimplify[-(1/2) Df[x - x4] J[x] - 1/2 Df[-x + x4] J[x],  
    Assumptions -> {Df[x] == Df[-x]}]
```

This code can not give the desired result which is `-Df[-x + x4] J[x]`.
The strange thing here is that if I replace `x4` with `x`2, it works well.

```
FullSimplify[-(1/2) Df[x - x2] J[x] - 1/2 Df[-x + x2] J[x], 
   Assumptions -> {Df[x] == Df[-x]}]
```

which gives `-Df[-x + x2] J[x]`.

So any solutions here for `x4` or arbitrary symbol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the simplest approach is:

```
Simplify[-(1/2) Df[x - x4] J[x] - 1/2 Df[-x + x4] J[x], Df[x - x4] == Df[-(x - x4)]]
```

> ```
> -Df[-x + x4] J[x]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, both of your cases did not work as intended in my version of Mathematica (12.2). I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for, but here are two methods of defining an even function which is to be used in **FullSimplify**

Using upvalues based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13345001):

```
Df[x_] + Df[y_] /; x == -y ^:= 2 Df[x];
FullSimplify[-(1/2) Df[x - x4] J[x] - 1/2 Df[-x + x4] J[x]]
```

that gives `-Df[x - x4] J[x]`. You could have used them in one line as in

```
Assuming[{Df[x_] + Df[y_] /; x == -y ^:= 2 Df[x]}, 
 FullSimplify[-(1/2) Df[x - x4] J[x] - 1/2 Df[-x + x4] J[x]]]
```

or alternatively:

```
FullSimplify[-(1/2) Df[x - x4] J[x] - 1/2 Df[-x + x4] J[x], 
 Assumptions -> {Df[x_] + Df[y_] /; x == -y ^:= 2 Df[x]}]
```

And here's another method:

```
ClearAll[Df];
Df[0] = 0;
Df[x_] /; Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ[x] := Df[-x];
FullSimplify[-(1/2) Df[x - x4] J[x] - 1/2 Df[-x + x4] J[x]]
```

which gives `-Df[x - x4] J[x]` which is the same as `-Df[-x + x4] J[x]`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider first reducing the arguments of Df to canonical form:

```
Simplify[-(1/2) Df[x - x4] J[x] - 1/2 Df[-x + x4] J[x] /. 
  Df[x_] :> Df@First@Sort[Simplify[{x, -x}]]]
```